The chapter and section format
I want to style the chapter in the following way. I do want the minitoc at each chapter, although not in the same format. The code I have is given below. I know that it will use tikz but I have no idea how to modify. Can anyone help me achieve this format. Thanks alot in advance.

            % arara: pdflatex
    % !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}

    % title format for the chapter
    % custom chapter
    \titleformat{\chapter}
    {\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries}                    % format applied to label+text
    {}                                                      % label
    {1pc}                                                   % horizontal separation between label and title body
    {
    \chapter
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth}%
            \raggedleft{%
                {\color{blue}\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont#1}%
            }%
        \end{minipage}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[cap=round,line width=6pt,blue]
          \draw[line width=2pt ] (0,0) -- (1.0\linewidth,0);
          \draw (0.7\linewidth,0) -- (1.0\linewidth,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
        \newcommand{\chaptertitle}[1]{ \chapter
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth}%
            \vspace*{0.5cm}
            \raggedright%
            #1%
        \end{minipage}%
                 } % before the title body
    []                        % after the title body


    \begin{document}
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    \lipsum[2]

    \end{document}

This is what I am getting


Before trying to do a complicate chapter layout, try a simple example with titlesec. This will help you find the syntax errors in your code.

I have tried that. simple code works. this one does not.
